# MongoDB replace value during aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose this document:

```
{
    _id : Object(“12918”),
    username : “username”,
    password : “password”,
    occupation: {
        name : “Football”,
        code : 254,
    }
},
{
    _id : Object(“12919”),
    username : “username2”,
    password : “password2”,
    occupation: {
        name : “Basketball”,
        code : 255,
    }
}
```

I want a query that returns:

```
{
    _id : Object(“12918”),
    occupation : {
        name : “*”,
        code : 254
    }
},
{
    _id : Object(“12919”),
    occupation : {
        name : “*”,
        code : 255
    }
}
```

So, a query that just returns the fields *_id* and *occupation*. And the field *occupation.name* must be replaced by * in all records.

I tried this query:

```
aggregate([
    {
        "$project" : 
        { 
            "_id" : 1, 
            “occupation" : 1,
            “occupation.name" : { $literal:“*” } 
        } 
    }
])
```

which returned the following exception:

> {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "can't add an expression for field occupation because there is already an expression for that field or one of its sub-fields.",
>       "code" : 16400
>   }

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your mongo server  version  ?

Comment: It's version 3.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the nested document projection of `occupation` like this :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "occupation": {
            code: 1,
            name: { $literal: "*" }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you Bertrand!

Comment: but how too using 0 or 1 value replace with other value because when using 0 or 1 value using for hide and show key but how to using 0 or 1 value for replace previous value

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{$project:{
           _id:1,
           occupation:{"name":{$literal:"*"},
                       "code":"$occupation.code"
                      } 
           }    
   }])
```